# php regex pregmatch remove zeros between characters

Tags: regex

I have a string and I want to achieve to remove all zeros between the characters `-s` and the first number.

```
1v-s001v => 1v-s1v
2v-s030r => 2v-s30r
3v-s021v => 3v-s21v
```

I'm trying with:

```
\w+-s0*(\d)
```

but it does not match the subject string.

Comment: You can use `-s\K0+(?=\d)` replace with empty string or Wiktor's capture group variation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
(-s)0+(\d)
```

and replace with `$1$2`. You may replace `\d` with `[0-9]` in case the `\d` is not supported by your regex flavor.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Con7AW/1)

**Details**

- `(-s)` - Capturing group 1 (later referred to with `$1` placeholder/replacement backreference from the replacement pattern): a `-s` substring
- `0+` - one or more `0` chars
- `(\d)` - Capturing group 2 (later referred to with `$2` placeholder/replacement backreference from the replacement pattern): any one digit